# Eclipse: Trying to convert CCombo "display" value to "storage" value

Tags: java, data-binding, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm building my plugin in Helios SR2.  It'd be Nice to support Galileo, but I'm not overly worried about it at this point. Windows 7: 64 bit, 64-bit JVM (1.6_21 IIRC).

---

I have an `swt.custom.CCombo` box filled with the display values of a list of entries.  I have a map of "display value" -> "storage value".

I want to store the storage value, and display the display value.  Go figure.

I'm using databinding with BeanObservables, IObservables, a DataBindingContext, all that jazz.

My current approach (that isn't working or I wouldn't be asking) is to create my own `UpdateValueStrategy` with a custom `IConverter` that'll internally map between the two.

I'm currently trying to extend `org.eclipse.core.databinding.conversion.Converter`, because IConverter is marked with `@noimplement` and `@noextend`.  The `@noimplement` states that clients should extend `Converter`rather than implementing IConverter directly (even though Converter is fairly trivial).

Sadly, Eclipse's Java compiler is telling me that's a no-no:

> Access restriction: The type Converter is not accessible due to restriction on required library {install}\plugins\org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.3.100.I20100601-0800.jar

In the relevant ".api_description", I see the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<component name="org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.3.100.I20100601-0800" version="1.2">
    <plugin id="org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.3.100.I20100601-0800"/>
    <package name="org.eclipse.core.databinding" visibility="1">
        <type name="ObservablesManager" restrictions="2"/>
        <type name="UpdateListStrategy" restrictions="0">
            <method name="useMoveAndReplace" restrictions="8" signature="()Z"/>
        </type>
    </package>
    <package name="org.eclipse.core.databinding.conversion" visibility="1">
        <type name="IConverter" restrictions="3"/>
    </package>
</component>
```

Rooting around thanks to Google Code, I see that `visibility="1"` means a public API.  Okay, great.

`restrictions="3"` on the other hand, means @noextend @noimplement.  Sound familiar?  Okay, great.

But it seems the restrictions on IConverter are rubbing off on Converter, making it impossible to use.  I cannot extend Converter, nor may I call `super(blah, blah)` from my constructor.  Interestingly enough, the compiler is *not* complaining about my implementation of `public Object convert(Object fromObject)` even though Converter doesn't have one of its own so one might think the `IConverter` restrictions would apply.

Clearly not.

Does anyone have

- An entirely different approach?
- Some means to beat this access restriction stuff into submission, preferably in a local kind of way so I don't do something dumb elsewhere.

I found the "restricted access" setting for the compiler and have switched it to "warn" rather than "error".  However, I'm hoping there's something a bit less global I could do.  I'll proceed with this in the mean time, but an alternative would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How Strange.

Okay, when I tried to use the auto-correct "include org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.3..." nothing happened.  I ass-u-me'd that it was correctly included as a plugin dependency and didn't fix the error.

During this time, that plugin's jar appeared in my plugin project's "Plug-in Dependencies" folder, and I was able to view its source.  One would think at that point that the plugin was correctly included in the plugin.xml

One would be wrong.

I manually added ...core.databinding_1.3... to my plugin dependencies and the errors Went Away.

So it seems this is a bug in the autocorrect rather than in the API restriction code.

AH!  I had org.eclipse.core.databinding in my Imported Packages list.  That must have thrown things off.

So now you know.  And knowing's have the battle.  GO CODE!

---

And speaking of code.  Here's what I'm doing (more or less):

```
enum MapValueDirection {
    VALUE_TO_KEY,
    KEY_TO_VALUE
};

private class MappingConverter extends Converter {
    Map<String, String> map = null;

    public MappingConverter( Map<String, String> map_, MapValueDirection dir) {
        super(String.class, String.class);
        if (dir == MapValueDirection.VALUE_TO_KEY) {
            map = reverseMap(map_);
        } else {
            map = map_;
        }
    }

    private Map<String, String> reverseMap(Map<String, String> map_) {
        Map<String, String> reversedMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        Set<Entry<String, String>> entries = map_.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, String> curEnt : entries) {
            reversedMap.put(curEnt.getValue(), curEnt.getKey());
        }
        return reversedMap;
    }


    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.eclipse.core.databinding.conversion.IConverter#convert(java.lang.Object)
     */
    public Object convert(Object fromObject) {
        if (map != null && fromObject != null && String.class.equals(fromObject.getClass())) {
            Object newVal = map.get(fromObject);
            if (newVal == null) {
                newVal = fromObject;
            }
            return newVal;
        }
        return fromObject;
    }
}

/**
 * And this is were the actual work gets done.
 */
public void bindBean(Object bean, PropertyDescriptor prop) {
  Control curControl = getControl(prop.getPropertyType());
  IObservableValue uiElement = getObserver(prop, curControl);
  IOvservableValue modelElement = BeanObservables.observValue(bean, prop.getName());

  // "display" = key, "storage" = value
  Map<String, String> profileFlds = getProfileFields();

  UpdateValueStrategy toStorage = new UpdateValueStrategy();
  toStorage.setConverter( new MappingConverter( profileFlds, MapValueDirection.KEY_TO_VALUE));

  UpdateValueStrategy toDisplay = new UpdateValueStrategy();
  toDisplay .setConverter( new MappingConverter( profileFlds, MapValueDirection.VALUE_TO_KEY));

  m_bindingContext.bindValue( uiElement, modelElement, toDisplay , toStorage);
}
```

My actual code is a bit more complex than that, but you get the idea.  I suspect it's not terribly efficient, but it works well within the whole data binding framework, conceptually speaking (based on my admittedly limited experience).

It should be fairly trivial to make a Generic version of MappingConverter, but I'll leave that as an Exercise For the Reader.